# wso2 client-checkin restore

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am using WSO2 Governance Registry v 4.6.0 and am trying to migrate the structure I have in an H2 backed test instance to a Postgres backed production instance (separate VMs for the Web server and database) using client-checkin.

I have successfully checked out the registry from the H2 instance but I am struggling to check it in to the Postgress system.

On the test instance I ran

```
./checkin-client.sh co https://localhost:9443/registry -u admin -p admin -f /../../../registry_checkout/registry.dump
```

to create the dump.

On the production system I executed

```
./checkin-client.sh ci https://arc-gov:9443/registry -u admin -p admin -f /../registry.dump
```

and get the following error below. (And yes I know the password is the same, it will change when I get it to work!).  The url here is that of the wso2 web server not the Postgres database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
[2014-10-09 10:34:05,672] ERROR -  Error in restoring the path. Make sure the registry is up and running Or the username, password is correct! and check the user have the WRITE permission to the path.
path: /
registry url: https://arc-gov:9443/registry
username: admin {org.wso2.registry.checkin.Client}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.synchronization.SynchronizationException: message code: ERROR_IN_RESTORING, parameters: {path: /, registry url: https://arc-gov:9443/registry, username: admin
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.synchronization.operation.CheckInCommand.restoreFromFile(CheckInCommand.java:207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.synchronization.operation.CheckInCommand.execute(CheckInCommand.java:164)
        at org.wso2.registry.checkin.Checkin.execute(Checkin.java:70)
        at org.wso2.registry.checkin.Checkin.execute(Checkin.java:56)
        at org.wso2.registry.checkin.Client.execute(Client.java:272)
        at org.wso2.registry.checkin.Client.start(Client.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.CheckinClientBootstrap.main(CheckinClientBootstrap.java:36)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Restoring to / failed.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.app.RemoteRegistry.restore(RemoteRegistry.java:1725)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.app.RemoteRegistry.restore(RemoteRegistry.java:1665)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.synchronization.operation.CheckInCommand.restoreFromFile(CheckInCommand.java:198)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Governance Registry does not support check-out , check-in from top level collection paths.[1]  *(i.e. /_system/governance/ and /_system/config/)*

Instead we recommend that you check-out check-in from child collection paths.

There seems to be an issue with dumping remote registry path collections on Greg 4.6.0. [2]

You can also find the fix attached to [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Check-in+Client+Examples

[2] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2044